# I created a 'Image from Folder" using Disk Utility, with Encryption and Files are Invisible

Tags: macos

I'm in a little over my head.   MacBook Pro, OSX 10.8.2:   I just created an  encrypted image (128 bits read/write), that Image Disk mounts fine...I can see the number of files and folders, but none of the files are visible to me.  I can see the subfolders, but none of the files at all.   Seems like using encryption for the partition was NOT good.

I've tried the Disk Utility to Convert the .PNG...I've tried to Restore the Image (folder) from the Partition, but I keep getting duplicates of the same Invisible Files.  I'm guessing I also can't delete these either.

The files are there, can be seen via the Terminal, but they are invisible.  Maybe because of attribute properties on the prefix of each file?   Each file starts with a "-rw-r--r--@".

Is `chmod` possible to adjust the attributes/?  Can anyone help with the right line entries.

Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance for any help.

kd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Image from Folder' will use the existing ownership/permissions of the folder and files.

First off, is the disk image a read/write image?  Are you able to add new files to it?  If not, the instructions below won't work if it is read-only.

The permissions you've listed, "-rw-r--r--@", mean that the file is read and writable by the owner and readable by everyone else.  The @ at the end means there are extended attributes to the file, which might include some kind of invisibility option.  You would have to get a directory listing with -@ to show the attribute keys.
For example, here is a listing showing an image that I manually set to be hidden.

```
$ ls -l@
-rw-r--r--@ 1 insom  staff  - 64832 Dec  6 18:56 FunnyImage.png
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32
```

If all your files also have a com.apple.FinderInfo attribute, use Terminal to change into the directory of the files and run the following command to unhide the files.

```
chflags nohidden *
```

Now, if your dir listing doesn't show the com.apple.FinderInfo attribute then they are not being hidden using this method but something else is going on.

Have you tried rebooting?  What about copying the disk image to a different computer and mounting it?

Comment: Yes, the disk image is read/write.  I just added a file and it is visible.

Comment: Let me also say that the folder was named "misc.noindex" before I Imaged it.

Comment: <<Sorry...I keep hitting 'return' and making new comments:>>

Here's a copy/paste from the Terminal:-rw-r--r--@ 1 kdouglas  staff  2503588 Jan  1 11:00 IMG_1542.JPG
 com.apple.FinderInfo      32 

I'll try the chflags command.   Thanks

Comment: chflags nohidden * Was the fix!!   Thank you sir!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it was an easy fix.  Please don't forget to approve this as the best answer.  No idea why it happened in the first place.  I tried creating an image named the same 'misc.noindex' just in case it was the noindex part that would set some strange parameter but it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, approved as best.  Only other oddity I can think of is the folder originated from a PC. Seems unlikely to be the problem.  Also...many of the newer files were drug from my iPhone using Parallels to see it as a drive.   That shouldn't change the folder properties though.